# How to get week number in google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

How to get week number in google-apps-script?

For example, this week is Week37, How to get the 37 from google apps script?

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to the top of your Apps Script:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}
```

Then you can use the getWeek method, for example to get this week:

```
var now = new Date();
Logger.log(now.getWeek());
```

Source: http://javascript.about.com/library/blweekyear.htm

Comment: this will NOT give you an iso week, just a way to approximate it. it also depends if weeks start on Sunday or monday. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Answer (score 17):

Maybe there was no such functionality in 2015, but now just you can:

```
var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "'Week'w"); 
// data = 'Week48' for example
```

You can use `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "u")` which returns the number of the day in a week (1-Monday, 7-Sunday) and update week number depending on its value.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Google Sheets start to count week numbers from Sunday.
If u want to start count from Monday you can do something like that:

```
function getWeek(date) {
  return Number(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "Europe/Kiev", "u")) === 7 ? 
    Number(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "Europe/Kiev", "w")) - 1 : 
    Number(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), "Europe/Kiev", "w"));
}
```

So the code will analyze if the day of the week equal to 7 (Sunday) it will returns (currentWeek - 1), else currentWeek.

And you have to specify timeZone param to your country time zone.
This is the second param in Utilities.formatDate, in my case that was "Europe/Kiev", but you can find zone that you need here:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#timezone-ids

If you need some more information what params you can throw in Utilities.formatDate you can find it here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html