# App script returns current week as 3 while it's week 2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To get the current week I have this piece of code:

```
 var today = new Date();
  var week = Utilities.formatDate(today, "Europe/Amsterdam", "w");
```

This returns `today` as `Tue Jan 12 2021 11:30:42` which is correct, as I am in Amsterdam. But it returns the current week as 3 while it's week 2. Looking back into last weeks logs, it returned week 2 while it was week 1. And the week before that, it returned week 53 which was correct. So this worked fine until the new year and it completely skipped week 1.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What makes you think it's week 2? Apps Script's [formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) is formats date according to Java's [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which also returns week 3. So, if this should actually be week 3 and not 2, then this would be an issue with the Java class, not with the Apps Script method.

Comment: I'm using the ISO week number format, which gives the current week as the second week of 2021. 
I found out it's not a App script problem, so was able to fix it with a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

I don't think there is an actual issue.

The confusion comes from the fact that week `1` started last year.

If you `console.log` all the dates starting from `26th of December 2020` until `12th of January 2021`:

```
function myFunction() {
  const December = [26,27,28,29,30,31];
  const January =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
  December.
  forEach(n=>{console.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2020,11,n), "Europe/Amsterdam", "yyyy-MM-dd"),"Week: ",
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2020,11,n), "Europe/Amsterdam", "w"))});
  January.
  forEach(n=>{console.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021,0,n), "Europe/Amsterdam", "yyyy-MM-dd"),"Week: ",
  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2021,0,n), "Europe/Amsterdam", "w"))});
}
```

you will get these results:

```
2020-12-26 Week:  52
2020-12-27 Week:  1 // Sunday
2020-12-28 Week:  1
2020-12-29 Week:  1
2020-12-30 Week:  1
2020-12-31 Week:  1
2021-01-01 Week:  1
2021-01-02 Week:  1
2021-01-03 Week:  2 // Sunday
2021-01-04 Week:  2
2021-01-05 Week:  2
2021-01-06 Week:  2
2021-01-07 Week:  2
2021-01-08 Week:  2
2021-01-09 Week:  2
2021-01-10 Week:  3 // Sunday
2021-01-11 Week:  3
2021-01-12 Week:  3
2021-01-13 Week:  3
```

Essentially, the `1st` week started last year on `2020-12-27` the `2nd` week on `2021-01-03` and the `3rd` week on `2021-01-10`, therefore the current week according to that logic is `3` which is the number you are getting.

### Workaround:

If you want to adjust this logic you can deduct `1` from the current week number so you will get `2` as the current number of week:

```
 var today = new Date();
 var week = Utilities.formatDate(today, "Europe/Amsterdam", "w") - 1;
```

Or you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432269/how-to-get-week-number-in-google-apps-script/47396482) and adjust the week number:

```
function exampleFunction() {
    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7)-1;
    } 
    var now = new Date();
    Logger.log(now.getWeek());
}
```

The only issue is that the first week of next year (which might be this year as well) will have `0` week number. But you can adjust this with an `if` condition to make sure it won't happen.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! 
Won't the workaround be outdated though once the week numbers align with the ISO week numbers again? 

I also find this answer that might fix my problem as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

Comment: @MichieltheTemp see my updated answer. The issue will be that in the first week of the next year you will have `0` but I guess you can adjust that with an `if` condition.